# sum all of greatest value of two fields mysql

Tags: mysql

I was trying to get all the greatest value in the table. Let say i have table named TableA and here is the attributes
My Current query is below which is only display one row. So the value that i want to get is sum of all the greatest value of all data.

```
SELECT GREATEST(MAX(Side-1-Length), MAX(Side-2-Length)) from TableA where DateEnd >='2017-11-10';
```

Below is my TableA

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| Id      | Side-1-Length| Side-2-Length|    DateEnd   |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 64      |      22      |      21      | 2011-11-14   |
| 187     |      32      |      26      | 2011-11-15   |
| 325     |      12      |      18      | 2011-11-15   |
| 389     |      41      |      36      | 2011-11-16   |
| 495     |      62      |      41      | 2011-11-14   |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The Query that i want to display will output something like below table

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| Id      | Side-Greates |    DateEnd   |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| 64      |      22      | 2011-11-14   |
| 187     |      32      | 2011-11-15   |
| 325     |      18      | 2011-11-15   |
| 389     |      41      | 2011-11-16   |
| 495     |      62      | 2011-11-14   |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

And WIll sum up all the Side-Greates value

```
+---------+
| Sum     |
+---------+
| 175     |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this query.

I used `CASE function()` in the query to check which side is greater and then choose it. I also used the `SUM() function` to sum all the greater value

```
SELECT 
SUM( CASE 
     WHEN Side-1-Length > Side-2-Length
     THEN Side-1-Length 
     ELSE Side-2-Length
     END
) as sum_of_all_greater_value 
FROM `TableA` 
WHERE DateEnd >='2017-11-10';
```

Comment: So if both side is same value, it will take any one of it?

Comment: @parkway yup it will. the else condition also handles that

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, using [IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) and then taking the [Sum()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(Side-1-Length > Side-2-Length, Side-1-Length, Side-2-Length))
FROM TableA
WHERE DateEnd >= '2017-11-10';
```

Comment: Thank both of the query works well. This make my query become more shorter